# How to write a function to cut many columns in R based on a control dataset

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe of chemical exposures that looks like this:

```
  chem1 chem2 chem3 ... chem524
  .06   6.8    .3        .2
  .7    24.3    NA       .7
  .4    2.9    .03       1.6
```

I need to convert the continuous values of each of the chemicals into categories based on the exposure value. The distribution of the values is very skewed, with many 0 values and a few very high values. These cuts need to be based off of the subset of the dataset that contains controls, that looks like the one above. The output should look like this:

```
      chem1_cut      chem2_cut     chem3_cut ...
      (-inf, 0.1]  (0.1, 12.1]  (0.1, 12.1]       
      (0.1, 12.1]  (12.1, inf]     NA      
      (0.1, 12.1]  (0.1, 12.1]  (-inf, 0.1]
```

Have been using the cut function like this for each individual chemical:

```
chem_dat$chem_1 <- cut(chem_dat$chem_1 , breaks=c(-Inf, quantile(control_chem_dat$chem_1 , probs=c( 0.5,0.75), na.rm=TRUE), Inf))
```

I want to be able to do this, or something like it, to all the columns inside of a function so that I don't have to write out what I have above 524 times. I cannot use the ntile function because it causes issues with extremely 0 inflated columns.

Here is what I have been trying:

chem_names <- colnames(chem_dat)

```
chem_cut <- map(chem_names, ~ chem_dat %>%
                       cut(  chem_dat$.x, 
                       breaks=c(-Inf, quantile(control_chem_dat$.x , probs=c(0.5,0.75), na.rm=TRUE), Inf)) %>% 
                       mutate(!!str_c(.x, "cut", sep = "_") := .x))
```

This is giving me the error

```
    Error in cut.default(., chem_dat$.x, breaks = c(-Inf, quantile(control_chem_dat$.x,  : 
  'x' must be numeric
```

How can I correct this function to do what I want? Or, is there a better way to do this task with some kind of package or something?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `chem_dat` and `control_chem_dat` are not the same data.frames, right? if this is the case, please provide an example of `control_chem_dat`

Comment: Yes, control_chem_dat is a different data.frame with the exact same format. Thank you for this suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `purrr` there are a map2* functions to iterate over multiple arguments simultaneously. When a data.frame is provided to `map*()`, it will iterate through the columns. Let's try it with an example dataset:

```
library(purrr)
set.seed(555)

control_chem_dat = data.frame(matrix(runif(10*3,min=0,max=0.5),ncol=3))
colnames(control_chem_dat) = paste0("chem",1:3)

chem_dat = data.frame(matrix(runif(5*3,min=0,max=1),ncol=3))
colnames(chem_dat) = paste0("chem",1:3)
```

Write a function to perform this task, given `x`, cut `y` like you have:

```
cut_y_by_x = function(x,y){
   cut(y,c(-Inf, quantile(x , probs=c(0.5,0.75), na.rm=TRUE),+Inf))
}
```

In base R we do this (so you can see the parallel in purrr) :

```
mapply(cut_y_by_x,control_chem_dat,chem_dat)
```

Let's do this in purrr:

```
map2_dfc(control_chem_dat,chem_dat,cut_y_by_x)
# A tibble: 5 x 3
  chem1         chem2        chem3       
  <fct>         <fct>        <fct>       
1 (0.453, Inf]  (-Inf,0.27]  (0.432, Inf]
2 (0.403,0.453] (0.351, Inf] (-Inf,0.383]
3 (0.453, Inf]  (0.351, Inf] (0.432, Inf]
4 (0.403,0.453] (0.27,0.351] (0.432, Inf]
5 (0.453, Inf]  (-Inf,0.27]  (-Inf,0.383]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this `base R` solution. It is considered that `chem_dat` and `control_chem_dat` are separated dataframes. In this example I set same values but you can replace. Hoping this can help:

```
#Data
chem_dat <- structure(list(chem1 = c(0.06, 0.7, 0.4), chem2 = c(6.8, 24.3,2.9),
                    chem3 = c(0.3, NA, 0.03), chem524 = c(0.2, 0.7, 1.6)),
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
#Data
control_chem_dat <- structure(list(chem1 = c(0.06, 0.7, 0.4), chem2 = c(6.8, 24.3,2.9),
                    chem3 = c(0.3, NA, 0.03), chem524 = c(0.2, 0.7, 1.6)),
               class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-3L))
#Function
cut_func <- function(x,y)
{
  z <- cut(y,breaks=c(-Inf, quantile(x , probs=c( 0.5,0.75), na.rm=TRUE), Inf))
  return(z)
}
#Apply
Result <- as.data.frame(mapply(cut_func,control_chem_dat,chem_dat))

        chem1       chem2        chem3     chem524
1  (-Inf,0.4]  (-Inf,6.8] (0.232, Inf]  (-Inf,0.7]
2 (0.55, Inf] (15.6, Inf]         <NA>  (-Inf,0.7]
3  (-Inf,0.4]  (-Inf,6.8] (-Inf,0.165] (1.15, Inf]
```

Comment: This is a nice solution, but I'm not sure if the breaks should be based on the quantiles of another df `control_chem_dat`

Comment: @starja it takes the quantiles according each column values. There is not other dataframe, just the one you have.

Comment: This was my first thought as well, but in the code by @Justin Andrew he actually uses the quantiles of `control_chem_dat` for the breaks of the data in `chem_dat`

Comment: @starja In such case, the second dataframe should be provided. But I understand you must only use one dataframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lapply` to generate the column index and apply the function to every column of your `chem_dat`. Using the index has the advantage that you can also index `control_chem_dat` (given that the columns are in the same order). This generates a list with an entry for every column, you can use `cbind` to bind it to a data.frame:

```
chem_cut_list <- lapply(seq_len(ncol(chem_dat)), 2, function(i)  {
  cut(chem_dat[, i] , breaks=c(-Inf, quantile(control_chem_dat[, i],
                                              probs=c( 0.5,0.75), na.rm=TRUE), Inf))
})

chem_cut <- do.call("cbind", chem_cut_list)
```